# Is my router/modem compromised?

Tags: nmap, attack-vector

So I recently ran a port scan (just TCP) on my home router/modem (AT&T U-Verse) and found two peculiar ports that are open. Here is the scan output/results for `nmap 192.168.1.254 -P0`:

```
Starting Nmap 6.49BETA4 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-14 14:30 UTC
Stats: 0:00:01 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 51.50% done; ETC: 14:31 (0:00:42 remaining)
Nmap scan report for homeportal (192.168.1.254)
Host is up (0.0045s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed PORT      STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp    open     http
256/tcp   filtered fw1-secureremote
443/tcp   open     https
49152/tcp open     unknown
```

The strange ports are 256(tcp) and 49152(tcp). The one I'm most concerned about is port 256. Doing some cursory research on Google, I found that `fw1-secureremote` (running on port 256) is used by VPN clients (SecuRemote). I've never used SecuRemote, let alone ever even heard of it.It also seems that port 256 is used by a trojan (Trojan.SpBot) which uses the device to send spam. Any insight please? Also, how might I go about contacting AT&T about this?

Comment: Try re-flashing and then see if the open ports go away. If they do, you had malware. Otherwise, it's probably something AT&T uses to control the router (and/or AT&T devices connected to it).

Comment: Is remote management enabled? If so on what port?

Comment: I would be initially more concerned about 49152 as the port reports its "open". Did you tried to identify what service is actually listening at that port?

Comment: @lepe I was not able to identify what service is listening at that port, seems to me that none of my devices are using that port. Any troubleshooting tips in that regard?

Comment: @RobertMennell remote management is NOT on :/.

Comment: At this point, the only thing you can do for more information is to either get lucky in a google search, or to attach a device between that and the modem to capture data on throughput. At this point reflashing with a known good image might be the better first step, and if that port is still open then it's probably something AT&T wants open. Here's hoping it's a VPN connection for AT&T.

Answer (score 3):

Is useless running a portscan against your internal IP address. You have to run it from outside your network against your public IP if you want to discover vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900623

In summary, port 49152 corresponds to nPNP port in some routers (in that thread is a D-link wbr-1310). Disabling it closed that port.

About port 256, as it is related to VPN, look into the VPN settings in your router.

Comment: I came across that thread too, unfortunately PNP is NOT running on the router. I also did a UDP scan on the router just now (was just interested) and found a bunch of filtered ports running on the router :

Comment: PORT     STATE   SERVICE
53/udp    open     domain
67/udp    open|filtered dhcps
776/udp   open|filtered wpages
1019/udp  open|filtered unknown
1050/udp  open|filtered cma
1993/udp  open|filtered snmp-tcp-port
19039/udp open|filtered unknown
19075/udp open|filtered unknown
20411/udp open|filtered unknown
20540/udp open|filtered unknown
22914/udp open|filtered unknown
24606/udp open|filtered unknown
30544/udp open|filtered unknown
37212/udp open|filtered unknown
44160/udp open|filtered unknown
49155/udp open|filtered unknown
49210/udp open|filtered unknown

Comment: Obviously, some are legit services, just not too sure on the other. Seems like I'm in for a fun weekend. Thanks everyone for the responses, I will update if/when I find something new out.